# $( "input" ).change(function () in Kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, onchange

I need to track if an element and if ye which element is changed in a form.

The $( "input" ).change(function () { handler is not firing in Kendo UI. My code is

```
$( "input" ).change(function () {
     alert('aaaa');
     event.preventDefault();
  });
```

what am I doing wrong? Or is there a more proper way in kendo?

Comment: What does "handler is not firing in Kendo UI" mean? How is Kendo UI involved in your code?

Comment: I didn't use any special functionality in Kendo for this event. But sometimes Kendo's own handler may prevent the execution of the handler you wrote

Comment: Which kendo controls you have used in your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `keyup` event.

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
  alert('aaaa');
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zCvTT/12/)**

Change event for input only fires when focus is lost after changing value. **[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/zCvTT/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

Give your input (for example #target) and them:

> jQuery( ".target" ).change(function() {
>
> > alert( "aaaaa" );
>
> });